# Unable to execute stored procedure in the dbo schema

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am connected to a SQL Server using Windows Authentication. I have created a stored procedure in the `dbo` schema. When I try to execute that stored procedure in SSMS, I am getting the following error

> The execute permission was denied on the object ‘sp_test’, database ‘myDB, schema = dbo

What need to be done here?

Why do I need to grant permission for me for a stored procedure that I created?

Comment: `sp_` is a reserved prefix for MS supplied procedures. You should avoid using such a prefix on your own stored procedures (and, generally, avoid any prefixes at all)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if you created the stored procedure. SQL Server does not use Windows authentication to determine if you have permission or not to execute a stored procedure. It only uses it to grant you permission to connect to the server. Once you are connected, you need to map your windows account to a user in the respective database. Once you do that, you typically would want to make yourself a member of a database role (either create a new one or use one of the predefined) and then grant execute permission to that role you are member of. This ensures that any member of this role can execute the stored proc going forward.

Comment: `to a Login in the respective database` I think you meant user.